# How to combine having serverless and docker in github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, serverless

I am running my tests on aws lambda with the use of custom image. I'm using serverless for the configuration and the build of the image.

Process works fine locally. When I try to make it work with github actions, using serverless/github-action@v3 I'm getting an error:

> Error: Could not find Docker installation. Ensure Docker is installed before continuing.

But since you can use 2 "uses:" I'm not sure how to work this one out. Any idea would be welcomed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Also please share your yml.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the action cannot find docker installation but I resolved it by running the serverless command directly as follows:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: "14"
  - run: npm i -g serverless
  - name: configure aws credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: ap-northeast-1
  - name: deploy
    run: sls deploy --stage dev --verbose
```